# MVVM Light Message not received when sending from ViewModel constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have got the following problem:

I am registering 4 ViewModels with the SimpleIoc in ViewModelLocator.
In the Contructor of MainViewModel I send a message to 2 of the other 3 ViewModels.
These messages are not received by these ViewModels.

The messaging in itself is working, because when I send a message later on these ViewModels react as expected.

So I expect the receiving ViewModels are not listening at the moment I send messages from the MainViewModel constructor. So I switched the sequence in which I register the ViewModels with SimpleIoc, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

**ViewModelLocator**

```
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginMethodVM>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<DatabaseConnDataVM>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<UserCredentialsVM>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<BrowserSelectionVM>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public LoginMethodVM LoginMethodVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<LoginMethodVM>();
        }
    }

    public DatabaseConnDataVM DatabaseConnDataVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<DatabaseConnDataVM>();
        }
    }

    public UserCredentialsVM UserCredentialsVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UserCredentialsVM>();
        }
    }

    public BrowserSelectionVM BrowserSelectionVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<BrowserSelectionVM>();
        }
    }
```

**MainViewModel**

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(System.Windows.Visibility.Visible, "UserCredentialsVisible");
        Messenger.Default.Send(System.Windows.Visibility.Visible, "BrowserSelectionVisible");
    }
```

**BrowserSelectionVM**

```
    public BrowserSelectionVM()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<System.Windows.Visibility>
            (this,
            "BrowserSelectionVisible",
            msg => { Visible = msg; });

    }
```

**UserCredentialsVM**

```
    public UserCredentialsVM()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<System.Windows.Visibility>
            (this,
            "UserCredentialsVisible",
            msg => { Visible = msg; });
    }
```

Comment: Are these View Models instantiated when you Send the message from MainViewModel

Comment: My hunch is that the receiver is not, but I cannot tell and changing the sequence does not help.

Comment: So, if you have not created an instance of the view model in memory, then the   Register  command does not run, so there is nothing registered to receive the message. Try this, before your MainViewModel constructor calls the Sends, create an instance of each view model.  The SimpleIOC has nothing to do with this problem since all it does is inject into your View Models, and you have no Constructor Arguments in your view model to inject into.

Comment: The ViewModels are created by by the ServiceLocator...GetInstance which is called when registering the VieModel I guess.

Comment: No, the View Models will only be created once you create an instance of them, either by directly opening an instance of them in code somewhere (UserCredentialVM test = new UserCredential();) or, by having them use the View Model Locator by opening a View where that View Model is the Data Context in XAML ( DataContext="{Binding UserCredentialVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"). The ServiceLocator does not create instances of View Models automaticaly.  Simply put a breakpoint in constructor of View Model that is registering to see it is not getting registered before you call the send message.

Answer (score 1):

ViewModelLocator.cs

```
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<UserCredentialsVM>(true);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<BrowserSelectionVM>(true);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public UserCredentialsVM UserCredentialsVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UserCredentialsVM>();
        }
    }

    public BrowserSelectionVM BrowserSelectionVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<BrowserSelectionVM>();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel MainViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
    }
```

BrowserSelectionVM.cs

```
public class BrowserSelectionVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public BrowserSelectionVM()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<System.Windows.Visibility>(this,
            "BrowserSelectionVisible",
            msg => { Console.WriteLine(msg); });
    }
}
```

UserCredentialsVM.cs

```
public class UserCredentialsVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public UserCredentialsVM()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<System.Windows.Visibility>(this,
            "UserCredentialsVisible",
            msg => { Console.WriteLine(msg); });
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(System.Windows.Visibility.Visible, "UserCredentialsVisible");
        Messenger.Default.Send(System.Windows.Visibility.Visible, "BrowserSelectionVisible");
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmLightRegistrationMock.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't see any difference.

Comment: @MPL I am not able to reproduce what you are seeing. In my test environment, I am able to see both of the visible messages. I have updated my answer and posted the code from my test environment.